# WPF приложение не видит новое окно

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

Я создал новое окно и хочу прописать показ формы через обработчик событий.

Определение окна (LoginScreen.xaml.cs):

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;

namespace Akhmad_Story
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Логика взаимодействия для LoginScreen.xaml 
    /// </summary> 
    public partial class LoginScreen : Window
    {

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AS Database;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        public LoginScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Opacity = 0.8;
        }

       //...    

    }
}
```

Window2.xaml.cs (файл, в котором используется окно):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
namespace Window2
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Interaction logic for Registration.xaml 
    /// </summary> 
    public partial class Registration : Window
    {
        public Registration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Opacity = 0.8;
        }

        //...

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoginScreen window = new LoginScreen();
            window.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

но Window2 отображается как ошибка, но я создал его 2 минуты назад

> 1>C:\Users\1\source\repos\AS\AS\Window2.xaml.cs(45,13,45,24)‌​: error
>   CS0246: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "LoginScreen"
>   (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку).
>
> 1>C:\Users\1\source\repos\AS\AS\Window2.xaml.cs(45,37,45,48)‌​: error
>   CS0246: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "LoginScreen"
>   (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку).
>
> 1>C:\Users\1\source\repos\AS\AS\Login.xaml.cs(24,13,24,14): warning
>   CS0414: Полю "LoginScreen.i" присвоено значение, но оно ни разу не
>   использовано.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86997/discussion-on-question-by---wpf-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был дан [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48045643#48045643):

> У вас LoginScreen в пространстве имен Akhmad_Story, а используете его в пространстве имен Window2. Добавьте в начало второго файла "using Akhmad_Story;", тогда должно заработать. А вообще, лучше оба окна поместить в одном пространстве имен